# Azure devops container jobs login issues with multiple jobs

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, containers

I am running a server with 10 azure devops agents. I have created a build that has 5 jobs and once in awhile we get an error initialize the container for a job. The image is already on the server so it doesn't need to download the image but as you can see the below log it fails to login

View raw log

```
'1.40'
Docker daemon API version: '1.40'
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE version --format '{{.Client.APIVersion}}'
'1.40'
Docker client API version: '1.40'
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE ps --all --quiet --no-trunc --filter "label=413526"
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE network prune --force --filter "label=413526"
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE login --username "***" --password *** https://***
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\devagent\.docker\config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
Login Succeeded
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE pull ***/builds/vs2017:1.0.0.0
Error response from daemon: Get https://***/v2/builds/vs2017/manifests/1.0.0.0: unauthorized: authentication required
##[warning]Docker pull failed with exit code 1, back off 3.597 seconds before retry.
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE pull ***/builds/vs2017:1.0.0.0
Error response from daemon: Get https://***/v2/builds/vs2017/manifests/1.0.0.0: unauthorized: authentication required
##[warning]Docker pull failed with exit code 1, back off 3.068 seconds before retry.
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE pull ***/builds/vs2017:1.0.0.0
Error response from daemon: Get https://***/v2/builds/vs2017/manifests/1.0.0.0: unauthorized: authentication required
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.EXE logout https://***
Not logged in to ***
##[error]Docker pull failed with exit code 1
Finishing
```

Yaml Build

```
variables:
    application.Name: 'Product'
    application.version: '5.12.0.0'
name: '$(application.name)_$(application.version)_$(Date:yyyMMdd)$(Rev:.rr)'

resources:
- repo: self
  clean: true
schedules:
- cron: "0 8 * * Mon-Fri"
  displayName: Nightly Build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - release/*/base

stages:

- stage: CI
  displayName: 'Continuous Integration'
  condition: |
    or(
      in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),
      and(
        in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),
        eq(variables['ManualCI'], 'true')
        )
      )
  jobs:
  - job: ProductCI
    displayName: Product
    condition: succeeded()
    pool:
      name: DW
    workspace: 
      clean: all
    timeoutInMinutes: 120

    steps:
    - template: templates/product-buildsteps.yml
    - template: templates/product-api-buildsteps.yml


  - job: AutomationCI
    displayName: Automation
    condition: succeeded()
    workspace: 
      clean: all
    pool:
      name: DW
    container:
      image: AzureContainerRepo/builds/vs2017:1.0.0.0
      endpoint: Azure Container Builds
    steps:
    - template: templates/product-automation-buildsteps.yml

  - job: FluentMigratorCI
    displayName: FluentMigrator
    condition: succeeded()
    workspace: 
      clean: all
    pool:
      name: DW
    container:
      image: AzureContainerRepo/builds/vs2017:1.0.0.0
      endpoint: Azure Container Builds
    steps:
    - template: templates/product-fm-buildsteps.yml

  - job: DeploymentCheckerCI
    displayName: Deployment Checker
    condition: succeeded()
    pool:
      name: DW
    container:
      image: AzureContainerRepo/builds/vs2017:1.0.0.0
      endpoint: Azure Container Builds
    steps:
    - template: templates/product-deploymentchecker-buildsteps.yml
```

Comment: Which system your container based? Windows? Or Linux?As a try, what about set `--signature-verification=false` to the Docker daemon configuration file?

Comment: These are windows containers running on windows server 2019 which have already been predownloaded to the servers. each container is based on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019. i have updated the main question with what the build looks as well